# Style QProgressBar when the value is 16

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qprogressbar

It is possible to style the `QProgressBar` using only `QSS` when the value is `16` example?

```
ui->progresso->setValue(16);
```

Using a QSS like this:

```
QProgressBar {
    //Default QSS
    ...
}

QProgressBar:value(16) {
    background-color: #fc0;
}
```

My goal is:
- When the `QProgressBar` is 0: It will use `background-color: transparent`
- When the `QProgressBar` is greater than 0: show a gray bar and the "chunk" will be blue
- When the `QProgressBar` is greater than 89: shows the "chunk" in red.

I can do this with `QT + C++`, but would like to know is it is possible to do this only with `QSS`?

Like this (this code does not exist, is just one example):

```
QProgressBar {
    background-color: gray;
}

QProgressBar:value(0) {
    background-color: transparent;
}

QProgressBar::chunk {
    background-color: blue;
}

QProgressBar::chunk:minValue(90) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible with help of Property Selector but only for exect values i.e.:

```
QProgressBar[value = 16]::chunk{
    background-color: red;
}
```

but you can generate such stilesheet in code for each value

```
QString styleSheet;
for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
{
    styleSheet.append(QString("QProgressBar[value = \"%1\"]::chunk{background-color: %2;}").arg(QString::number(i), (i < 17 ? "red" :"blue")));
}
myProgressBar->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```

I don't try it. It's just a theory based on documentation.
**Update 1**

```
Warning: If the value of the Qt property changes after the style sheet has been set, it might be necessary to force a style sheet recomputation. One way to achieve this is to unset the style sheet and set it again.
```

Comment: yep, I dont read the warning to property selector here it is Warning: If the value of the Qt property changes after the style sheet has been set, it might be necessary to force a style sheet recomputation. One way to achieve this is to unset the style sheet and set it again.

Comment: I've tried that but doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The only valid extensions are in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/stylesheet-reference.html) and too long to post here.

However you could handle the `valueChanged( int )` signal of the `QProgressBar`
and set the stylesheet accordingly using `setStyleSheet( )` but I figure you already know that.